# Creating Pipes with array in loop

Tags: c, pipe

I need to create 10 pipes in C. 
In order to make them work I need to create 10 int arrays of size 2? Or can I just declare an array sized 20 and then give the pipe the adress where each pipe should start?
If I have to create 10 is there any way i can create them in a loop and get kind of this result?

```
for(i=0; i<10; i++){
    vec0[2];    //create array vec0, vec1, vec2....
    pipe(vec0);
}
```

Is even an array the best way to do this?

Comment: There are no vectors in C. Do you mean arrays?

Comment: The code shown leaks 20 file descriptors. You could create an array of 20 `int` outside the loop and use an appropriate offset to the array inside the loop.

Comment: yes, I ment an array sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just use 2 dimensional `int` array as below.

```
int fds[10][2];
for(i=0; i<10; i++){
   pipe(fds[i]);
}
```

Where `fds[i][0]` represents read end and `fds[i][1]` represents write end.

---

If you don't want to use 2 dimensional array then you can declare array with 20 `int`s as below and use offset based approach to pass and read the `fd's`.

```
 int fds[20];
 for(i=0; i<10; i++){
       pipe(fds+i*2);
    }
```

Then`fds[i*2]` represents read end and `fds[i*2+1]` represents write end.

Answer (score 2):

> I need to create 10 pipes in C. In order to make them work I need to create 10 int arrays of size 2?

That would be one alternative, but not the only one.

> Or can I just declare an array sized 20 and then give the pipe the adress where each pipe should start?

Yes, you could do that.  The `pipe()` function in any case receives only a pointer to the first `int`, and requires that one subsequent one to be addressable via that pointer.

> If I have to create 10 is there any way i can create them in a loop and get kind of this result?

Yes, you could declare a two-`int` array in a loop, pass it to `pipe()`, and copy out the result to some more permanent storage before the next iteration, but that would be wasteful.

The first thing to consider is how you want to store the pipe-end file descriptors.  If you need them only for the duration of the loop then you can just keep reusing the same array, or use a per-loop-iteration array such that there only ever is one.

But suppose you want only to create the pipes in the loop, such that you need to keep track of all their file descriptors after the end of the loop.  For such a case, the most natural data structure for holding just the file descriptors would be an array of arrays, a.k.a. a 2D array:

```
int pipefds[10][2];
```

If you were planning to use such a structure, then your loop might look like this:

```
int pipefds[10][2];

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    pipe(pipefds[i]);
}
```